# SET /a var= grep -wc word file.txt in BATCH

Tags: batch-file, grep

In BATCH file,how to get correct answer for

```
SET /a var= grep -wc word file.txt
echo %var%
```

means I want the output of grep command to be stored in variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a variable to the output of a command, use a `for /f` loop.  In a cmd console, type `for /?` for more information.

```
for /f %%A in ('grep -wc word file.txt') do set "var=%%A"
echo %var%
```

Comment: Hey @rojo, from where have  you learnt BATCH script?
Your knowledge is too good.

Comment: @AbhiKumarSahu Mostly just from trial and error.  I've learned quite a bit hanging around here, though, and from sites like [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/) and [DosTips.com](http://dostips.com/).  jeb, dbenham, MC ND, npocmaka, and many others who answer questions here seem to have a limitless amount of knowledge of batch scripting.  And I learn a lot by finding my own solutions to other people's problems.  I think you learn more when you have to teach someone else what you have learned.